# Mobile application + Spring MVC - JSP?

Tags: json, jsp, rest, spring-mvc, model-view-controller

I've got a web application built over Spring MVC, already working. I'm planning to give mobile users an app for communicating with the server, so they will find easier to interact with it. I've got the Model, the Views and the Controllers working fine, but everything was designed from the web's perspective.

So, I'm building up a few new Controllers for the mobile app, and here comes the question: since the ultimate rresponsible of the View is going to be the mobile app in question, where should I delegate everything to the app, in the Controller (preparing there a JSON for each response)? Or should I have a JSP with some JSON taglib enabled, so that the Controller gives the pieces to the JSP, and then I build the JSON response in the JSP?

I'm not clear about the MVC architecture on this scenario.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When all you are doing is creating a REST API which mobile (or other clients) are going to use, Views do not come into play. It's the responsibility of the Controller to prepare the appropriate response for the client.

Luckily since returning JSON is such a common scenario, Spring MVC transparantly handles the serialization into JSON (using the Jackson library) so you don't have to.

As JB Nizet showed, you can use the `@ResponseBody` annotation to tell Spring MVC that the response should be returned as is (serialized to JSON because of the `produces = MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE`) or if you are using Spring 4, you can completely ditch the `@ResponseBody` annotation and annotate your Controller with `@RestController` (which makes Spring behave as if `@ResponeBody` was added to every method mapping) instead of `@Controller`.

Answer (score 1):

The controller methods should simply return obejcts (or collections of objects), that will be serialized to JSON automatically thanks to the @ResponseBody annotation:

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/api/users", 
                method = RequestMethod.GET, 
                produces = MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE)
@ResponseBody
public List<User> listUsers() {
    ...
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I've been using `@ResponseBody` for handling AJAX calls through the web app, so OK I think this would make it. I'm marking the other answer as "the answer" just because it tells a little bit more about my doubts about MVC and mobile app development.